# LC transfer function

Tags: transistors, filter, transfer-function, band-pass

How would I go about deriving a transfer function or expected cut-off frequencies for this LC moveable bandpass filter (wah-wah effect)?

[image: circuit design]

Comment: If you have no access to any mental tools to do so, you wouldn't go about deriving the transfer function. You'd pay someone else to do that for you or you would use a simulator and let it punch out the data you wanted. What mental tools do you possess and feel comfortable applying in the direction of developing what you want out of this circuit? Or would suggestions about how to use simulation be good enough for you?

Comment: If we exclude the dc-block capacitors like the series 10-nF at \$Q_1\$'s base and the two right-side 0.22-µF ones, then this is a 3rd-order filter. If I had to do that, I would use the fast analytical circuits techniques (FACTs) but applying them for the first time to a circuit like this would be a perilous exercise.

Comment: Use a simulator.

Comment: @periblepsis some guidance on using a simulator would be really helpful

Comment: @Lexifare26 Do you have a simulator that you already use?